# Can we solve this ODE?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I am considering the ODE

$$y'(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1-\sin(x-\frac{\pi}{4})\\ 1 - \sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) & 0 \end{pmatrix} y(x).$$

My question is: Can we find an explicit solution to this ODE? A solution clearly exists, but I am wondering if one can find it explicitly?

Comment: *Mathematica 10.0* does not seem to give any closed-form solution.

Comment: This is completely standard except for matrices: $\frac{dy}y=(\text{your matrix})dx$ gives$$y=\exp\left(\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&x+\sin(x+\frac\pi4)\\x-\sin(x-\frac\pi4)&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)+\text{any constant matrix}\right)$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე mhmm, but so what you did is that you computed the antiderivative $B(x)$ of the matrix, let's call it $A(x)$. But this way wouldn't we have. So $y(x) = exp(B(x))$ but then $y'(x)= y(x)A(x)$ by the chain rule. So why is this the same as $A(x)y(x)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. By some reason I expected that $y$ and the antiderivative would commute, but now I cannot actually find any reason to expect it.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  it works when the coefficient matrix commutes with its derivative

Comment: In general, $\big(e^{B(x)}\big)'$ is not $e^{B(x)}B'(x)$ nor $B'(x)e^{B(x)}$, unless $B$ and $B'$ commute

Comment: Variable coefficient linear ODEs as a general rule don't have explicit solutions as soon as the order exceeds $1$.

Comment: Look up Floquet theory for periodic coefficients  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory

Comment: found an undergraduate project on Floquet, https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/17640/1/bMATH_2018_FolkersE.pdf  Not sure yet if we can explicitly   calculate the monodromy matrix if we cannot explicitly write down a fundamental matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer: the system reduces to a Riccati equation.

We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
y_1'&=(1-\sin(x-\frac\pi4))y_2,\\
y_2'&=(1-\sin(x+\frac\pi4))y_1.
\end{aligned}
$$
The function $z=y_1/y_2$ satisfies
$$
z'=y_1'/y_2-y_1y_2'/y_2^2=1-\sin(x-\frac\pi4)-(1-\sin(x+\frac\pi4))z^2.
$$
Once $z$ is found $y_1$ and $y_2$ can be found from it in terms of antiderivatives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\log y_1)'&=(1-\sin(x-\frac\pi4))/z\\
(\log y_2)'&=(1-\sin(x+\frac\pi4))z.
\end{aligned}
$$
As for the Riccati equation, if desired, it can be made algebraic (in fact, with rational function coefficients): the substitution $\tan(\frac{x-\pi/4}2)=t$ gives
$$
\frac{dz}{dt}=2 \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{2tz}{1+t^2}\right)^2
$$
It can be also turned into a second order linear equation. Beyond that, I don't know. I would say, it is sort of generic kind of a Riccati equation.

To look at the qualitative picture, here is a stream plot (from Mathematica) in the $(x,z)$-plane

[image]